# Finding/merging two objects with a common property

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Please excuse the long question. I'm just not sure what the best approach to this problem is.

I have a spreadsheet (Google Sheet) with a list of users and addresses, from which I need to create mailing labels. This spreadsheet is an export from our student information system. The addresses are SUPPOSED to be shared between users who live in the same house, but because of errors in our database, some users who should be sharing an address have separate instances of the same address. See below (represented as CSV):

```
Address ID,Address,User
-----------------------
100,Boston,Bob
100,Boston,Joan       //Note, same address ID AND address -this is correct
200,Boston,Geoff      //DIFFERENT address ID and address -wrong
300,New York,Steve    //Just here for contrast
```

I need to create "households" from this information. I can't count on it to always be correct in the source data (users don't always know how to use shared addresses), and I don't want to have to manipulate the spreadsheet before I run it through my script.

So far, this is how I've approached the problem:

**Create objects, then match objects with the same address property and merge them.**

After processing, I have the following nested objects:

```
var masterObj = {
    100: {"address": "Boston",
         "users": ["Bob","Joan"]
    },
    200: {"address": "Boston",
         "users": ["Geoff"]
    },
    300: {"address": "New York",
         "users": ["Steve"]
    }
}
```

I want to find objects whose "address" properties are equal, then merge the two objects

```
//Result should be:

var masterObj = {
    100: {"address": "Boston",
         "users": ["Bob","Joan","Geoff"],
    300: {"address": "New York",
         "users": ["Steve"]
    }
}
```

---

I am open to other alternatives that involve doing the matching/merging BEFORE creating objects. I'm trying to use objects because there are several different ways this information may be handled, and I want to allow my project to be easily adaptable.

Also, because this is Google Apps Script, I would prefer a pure javascript solution, but I can deal with libraries if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you started with following rows object mapping the rows of excel

```
var rows = 
[
    {addressId:100,address:'Boston',user:'Bob'},
    {addressId:100,address:'Boston',user:'Joan'},
    {addressId:200,address:'Boston',user:'Geoff'},
    {addressId:300,address:'New York',user:'Steve'}
];
```

and maintained a hashMap kind of object to check and merge duplicate

```
var addressMap = {}; //{key: address, value: addressId}
```

you could have used reduce and duplicate merge to get your final masterObj

```
var masterObj = rows.reduce(function(previous, next){
    if(addressMap[next.address]){
        previous[addressMap[next.address]].users.push(next.user);
    } else {
        previous[next.addressId] = {address: next.address, users: [next.user]};
        addressMap[next.address] = next.addressId;
    }
    return previous;
}, {})
```

See working jsBin [here](https://jsbin.com/wiqetixoho/edit?js,console)

Comment: Perfect. Never thought of using reduce to build an object. I actually simplified my data for the question, so I had to adapt this significantly but the concept is exactly what I needed.